# Passing a php variable as string to mysql as part of SELECT

Tags: mysql, variables, select

In setting up a pivot table with dynamic dates. I'm hitting a logic wall when it comes to inserting the string generated from my first mysql query into the second.

when I

```
echo $rowstring
```

echo generates

```
SUM( IF( `InvDate`='20160106', round(InvTotalIncl,2), 0 ) ) AS `20160106`,
SUM( IF( `InvDate`='20160107', round(InvTotalIncl,2), 0 ) ) AS `20160107`
```

Testing the output via the following query:

```
    select InvOperCode,
    SUM( IF( `InvDate`='20160106', round(InvTotalIncl,2), 0 )     )
    AS `20160106`,
    SUM( IF( `InvDate`='20160107', round(InvTotalIncl,2), 0 ) ) 
    AS `20160107`
    FROM `invoice_hdr_tbl`
    where InvDate between '20160101' and '20160131'
    group by InvOperCode
```

I get my desired result.

However when I try and pass the first query as string to the second query via

```
$result = mysql_query("select InvOperCode,'.$rowstring.'
FROM `invoice_hdr_tbl`
where InvDate between '20160101' and '20160131'
group by InvOperCode");
```

I receive an error "Query to show fields from table failed" Which is my line of code, so I know there is an error with my 2nd db query.

```
if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
```

I think I'm not getting the string conversion correct and or the quoting of a variable in the "select" part of my query.

Any help would be appreciated.

PS I left

```
echo $rowstring;
```

in my code to identify the point at which the I'm viewing the query and stating the echo as correct. For whatever reason the it then does not pass correctly to my db query

Here's my code thus far.

```
$resultlength = mysql_query("SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000");


$concatresult = mysql_query("
select group_concat(distinct CONCAT('SUM( IF( `InvDate`=\'',`InvDate`,'\', round(InvTotalIncl,2), 0 ) ) AS `',`InvDate`,'`'))
as Data
FROM `invoice_hdr_tbl`
where InvDate between '20160101' and '20160131'
order by InvDate");
if (!$concatresult) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}

$rowarray = mysql_fetch_assoc($concatresult);

$rowstring = $rowarray['Data'];
echo $rowstring;


$result = mysql_query("select InvOperCode,'.$rowstring.'
FROM `invoice_hdr_tbl`
where InvDate between '20160101' and '20160131'
group by InvOperCode");

if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
}
$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

echo "<h1>Sales Report </h1>";
echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
// printing table headers
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{
    $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
    echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
}
echo "</tr>\n";
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";


    foreach($row as $cell)
        echo "<td>$cell</td>";

    echo "</tr>\n";
}
mysql_free_result($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution, it was simple and overlooked:

```
$result = mysql_query("select InvOperCode,'.$rowstring.'
FROM `invoice_hdr_tbl`
where InvDate between '20160101' and '20160131'
group by InvOperCode");
```

should be

```
 $result = mysql_query("select InvOperCode,$rowstring
    FROM `invoice_hdr_tbl`
    where InvDate between '20160101' and '20160131'
    group by InvOperCode");
```